# aggregate array attribute and convert to csv

Tags: arrays, json, csv, sum, jq

I have the following file ( vms.json ) that i am trying to convert csv while adding the disk size element.

**vms.json**

```
    {
"vms": [
{
  "hostname": "host1",
  "state": "running",
  "platform": "linux",
  "Disks": [
    {
      "index": 1,
      "volume_name": "/boot",
      "size": "34359738368"
    },
    {
      "index": 2,
      "volume_name": "/data",
      "size": "27917287424"
    }
 ]
},
{
  "hostname": "host2",
  "state": "running",
  "platform": "linux",
  "Disks": [
    {
      "index": 1,
      "volume_name": "/boot",
      "size": "34359738368"
    },
    {
      "index": 2,
      "volume_name": "/user_data",
      "size": "5159324276"
    },
    {
      "index": 3,
      "volume_name": "/temporary",
      "size": "102400"
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

**vms.csv**

```
hostname,state,platform,Disks
host1,running,linux,62277025792
host2,running,linux,39519165044
```

I would like to use jq to perform this conversion, however 
How can this be achieved using jq and @csv filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your input and an invocation of jq with the -r option, the following filter:

```
 .vms[]
| [.hostname, .state, .platform, (.Disks | map(.size|tonumber) | add)]
| join(",")
```

produces:

```
host1,running,linux,62277025792
host2,running,linux,39519165044
```

Adding the headers and exploring what happens when `join(",")` is replaced by `@csv` are left as exercises :-)